# module pandas has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the error:

```
import pandas as pd
participants = pd.DataFrame({'name' : name,
            'email' : emails,
            "KU ID" : ku_id,
            "number" : number,
            "Position" : position,
            'section' : section,
            'status' : status,
            'food' : food,
            'find' : find,
            'abstract' : abstract}) 
    
> module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

I have noticed others have gotten this error and it seems to normally be related to the parent directory having a `pandas.py` file in it. I have no such file so am unsure what could be causing this issue.

However both `pd.__version__` and `pd.show_version()` return the same error which would indicate something is really wrong with whatever the pandas is that I am importing? `pd.__file__` returns nothing also!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling pandas?

Comment: or you have a file called `pandas.py`

Comment: @AsishM. I do not as stated in the queston.

Comment: @superepicprogrammer I have not, I will try but it is odd the function would suddenly stop doing this?

Answer (score -1):

**import pandas as pd**

df1= {
'Country':['india','USA','RUSSIA'],
'population':[140,30,15]
}

df1 =pd.DataFrame(df1)

df2= {'Country':['india','USA','RUSSIA'], 'Capital':['Dlehi','London','Moscoe'] }
df1 =pd.DataFrame(df1)

df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)

pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',on='Country')

*kindly find small example for reference.*